# Large geodesically convex subsets of tori

Tags: convex-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Let $X=\mathbb T^d=\mathbb R^d/\mathbb Z^d$ and let $E$ be a proper open subset of $X$. We say $E$ is *geodesically convex* if for any $x,y\in E$ the **shortest** geodesic connecting $x$ and $y$ lies in $E$.

**Question.** How large can the Haar/Lebesgue measure of $E$ can be?

For example, is $d=2$, then it seems that this cannot exceed $1/2$. Say, $[0,1)\times [0,s)$ is geodesically convex if and only if $s\leq1/2$. (If $s>1/2$, then $[x,x+\delta]$ is not the shortest geodesic for any $\delta\in(1/2,s)$ and any $x\in(0,1)$.)

Is it true for any $d\ge2$ that the measure of such an $E$ cannot exceed $1/2$?

Comment: No, it doesn't - that's my point exactly. 

Comment: Why isn't it? in your example the shortest one is of length $1/4$, `going round' on level $y=1/4$ but staying inside $E$. Am I wrong? 

Comment: Your question is obvious for the circle. Partition the torus into geodesic circles and apply fubini. It seems to work...

Comment: Thought about it but couldn't figure out how to do it rigorously. It is not true that each section has measure $\le1/2$, that's for sure. It sort of depends on whether we're trying to `stretch' it horizontally or vertically...

Comment: Nikita, I misunderstood, you did type it in correctly and I missed that you were wrapping around in one direction, although not the other. I imagine your figure of 1/2 is correct. I did a long thing with a youngster named Dror Atariah in Germany, there was a little bit on MO and a bunch of email. We never did decide the thing. My main impression is that you can do what you like as long as the boundary of the set $E$ is totally geodesic and other conditions (such as symmetry) are favorable. Proving you cannot do better than 1/2 is another matter.

Comment: Will, thanks for your comment. I kinda hoped that this was well known for a wide class of Riemannian manifolds tbh... such a natural question, after all. Googling didn't help though, so I turned to MO. The question is ancillary for me, related to the dynamics of maps with holes, so I didn't want to spend too long on it. Perhaps, I should, after all. 

Comment: Just take a small ball that is not in E then choose a small rational slope so that after we partition the torus into the circles each circle would intersect the ball... 

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*(This is a new answer; my original answer was completely wrong.)*

Assume $\mathop{\rm vol}E>\tfrac12$.
Then it contains two opposite points say $x$ and $x'=x+(\tfrac12,\tfrac12,\dots,\tfrac12)$.
WLOG we can assume that $x=0$.
Taking minimizing geodesics form $(\tfrac12,\tfrac12,\dots,\tfrac12)$ to $y\approx 0$, we get that all main diagonal of unit cube 
$$\square^n=(0,1)\times(0,1)\times\dots\times(0,1)$$ 
lie in $E$. 
Then apply the following lemma:

**Trivial Lemma.** Let $\square^n$ be open unit cube in $\mathbb R^n$ and $E\subset \square^n$ be a locally convex open set which contains all main diagonals of $\square^n$ then $E=\square^n$.

To prove the lemma, note that local convexity + conectedness in $\mathbb R^n$ implies convexity.

Answer (score 2):

Let me write down the steps.

1. Consider the case d=2, the generalization is straightforward.
2. There is an open ball B that doesn't intersect E.
3. Consider two families of geodesic circles F_1 and F_2. F_1 has slope 1/p and F_2 has slope 1-1/p. Number p is chosen in such a way that each circle from F_1 nd F_2 intersects B.
4. Claim:  $Leb(E\cap F_1(x))\le 1/2 length(F_1(x))$ OR $Leb(E\cap F_2(x))\le 1/2 length(F_1(x))$ for each x.
5. Proof: $E\cap F_1(x)$ is a proper union of open intervals that are separated by gaps of length at least $\sqrt{p^2+1}/2p$. So it remains to show that there are at least $p$ gaps. If there are less than $p$ gaps then there is an interval from $E\cap F_1(x)$ of length greater than $\sqrt{p^2+1}/2p$. It follows that one can find a simple closed curve C_1 in E which is C^0 close to a horizontal generator.
   Assume that in the same way we also can find C_2 in E which is C^0 close to the vertical generator. Then one can easily see that E is the torus and the claim follows.
6. Apply Fubini.

Comment: Sorry, don't understand it, starting with 3. Geodesic circles are either vertical or horizontal, aren't they? So, what do you mean by `slope'? With a slope geodesics will not be even closed. 

Comment: Nikita, take any line through the origin with rational slope, so $y = \frac{m}{n} \; x.$ This line also passes through the lattice point $(n,m).$ This point is identified with the origin in the torus you define, so it is a closed curve. For example, the line $y = x$ is a closed geodesic in the torus. It is instructive to draw the image of, say,  $y = \frac{5}{3} \; x$ in the original 1 by 1 square under identification.

Answer (score 1):

A bit long for a comment. You can have a geodesically convex set that is an arbitrarily large proportion of the area of a surface. What I have in mind resembles a [bulb_thermometer](http://www.howstuffworks.com/therm1.htm) or [turkey_baster](http://www.chefsresource.com/turkey-baster.html)  but is at least $C^\infty.$ It is rotationally symmetric. One end is  long, cigar shaped, half of something that approximates a [prolate spheroid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prolate_spheroid).  It differs from an actual prolate spheroid in that it is necessary for the Gauss curvature to be 0 along the "equator," the closed geodesic where the half cigar joins the bulb. Therefore the curvature must approach 0 near the equator. Immediately upon entering the bulb section, the curvature is slightly negative, which is the reason geodesics leaving the equator cannot quickly return.